# Calculate loading time of multiple websites using AsyncTask in Xamarin Android and C#.Net

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a string array which contains addresses of websites:

```
string[] arr = new string[]
                {
                    "https://www/google.com",
                    "https://www.yahoo.com",
                    "https://www.microsoft.com"
                };
```

I have to send these URLs as argument to the `asynctask` method so that I will be able to calculate the loading time of each website. I don't have to show the website pages, so I am not using `webview`.

I can use stopwatch or `httprequest` to calculate the loading time and my ultimate goal is that all the websites need to start loading at the same time asynchronously, and output has to look like the following

**Loading time**

> google - 00:00:04:092345 (hr:min:sec:millisec) yahoo - 00:00:06:028458

How can I send an array to `asynctask` and how I can generate loading time without using await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //Create TextView to display status of Wifi
       TextView wifitext = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.WifiTextView);

        //Configuring Wifi connection
        var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
        var activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;

        if (activeConnection != null && activeConnection.IsConnected)
        {
            wifitext.Text = "WIFI AVAILABLE";

            string[] urladdress = new string[] { "https://www.google.com/", "https://www.yahoo.com/"};


            for (int i = 0; i < urladdress.Length; i++)
            {
                string url = urladdress[i];

                //Call async method
                Task returnedTask = Task_MethodAsync(url);
            }

         }
        else
           wifitext.Text = "WIFI UNAVAILABLE";        
    }

    public async Task Task_MethodAsync(string url)
    {
        LinearLayout ll = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
       Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        Stream listurl = client.OpenRead(url);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(listurl);

        stopwatch.Stop();
        // listurl.Close();

        var time = Convert.ToString(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief solution of what you could do.

*This is not complete nor perfect. It will will give you the loading time of one URL. Also there is a suggestion of how you could extend this to multiple URLs.*

You will need a `WebView`, either in code or from UI.

Load the URL into the `WebView` using `webview.LoadUrl("https://www/google.com");`.

Create a new `class` by extending it from `WebViewClient` as follows:

```
public class myWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        Console.WriteLine("OnPageFinished for url : " + url + " at : " + DateTime.Now);
    }
 }
```

In your `OnCreate()` method add the following line of code :

```
 webview.SetWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
```

So from here what you have to do is, Create a `Dictionary` with URL as `key` and Loading time as `value`. Set all the loading time to 0 initially. Update the value corresponding to each URL in the `OnPageFinished()`. Create an `async Task` function which would return you the populated dictionary.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, double>> myAsyncFunction()
{
     await Task.Delay(5);  //to make it async
     //Wait till all the OnPageFinished events have fired. 
     while (myDictionary.Any(x=>x.Value == 0) == true)
     {
         //there are still websites which have not fully loaded. 
         await Task.Delay(1);  //wait a millisecond before checking again
     }
     return myDictionary;
}
```

You can call `myAsyncFunction()` in a seprate thread than your UI and implement the `ContinueWith()` or just let it run in a separate thread and write that output into somewhere that you can check when required. 
eg : `Task.Run(async () => await myAsyncFunction());`

**UPDATE :** *based on OP's comments*

In the UI thread :

```
  var myClassList = new List<myClass>
  { 
       new myClass{URL = "https://www/google.com", TimeTaken = null},
       new myClass{URL = "https://www.yahoo.com", TimeTaken = null},
       new myClass{URL = "https://www.microsoft.com", TimeTaken = null}
  };

   Console.WriteLine("Started at : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

   var business = new BusinessLogic();
   var loadtimetask = business.GetLoadTimeTakenAsync(myClassList);
   await loadtimetask;

   Console.WriteLine("Completed at : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

And implementation class :

```
public async Task<List<myClass>> GetLoadTimeTakenAsync(List<myClass> myClassList)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(myClassList, myClassObj =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    myClassObj.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                    var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(myClassObj.URL)
                                        .ContinueWith((s) =>
                                        {
                                            if (s.IsCompleted)
                                            {
                                                var myClassObjCompleted = myClassList.Where(x => x.URL == myClassObj.URL).First();
                                                myClassObjCompleted.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
                                                myClassObjCompleted.TimeTaken = myClassObj.EndTime - myClassObj.StartTime;
                                            }
                                        });
                    Task.Run(async () => await stream);
                }
            });

            while (myClassList.Any(x => x.TimeTaken == null))
            {
                await Task.Delay(1);
            }

            return myClassList;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit......I used dynamic textview to print the output. could you please tell how to use await function on this line. I used async method to read chunks of data of url with this statement. Stream listurl = client.OpenRead(url);

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you are trying to do. Can you please update the question as an edit?

Comment: What I am trying to do is.........I am printing the result as follows............    Google -- 00:00:00:04:5678                                                                 Yahoo -- 00:00:00:04:5678     I am printing them in a loop synchronously. What I need to do is when the request is sent if the response is still pending it has to send another request and check the response once again. when response is found I have to print output............asynchronous way of doing. I need to send request asynchronously and record o/p using await

Comment: Start multiple requests and calculate loading time of each website as they complete loading------asynchronously using async/await

Comment: I think you would be better of using [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please help me with example

Comment: @Angel - Could you see if the Edit is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi...I did not use task.delay(). Tested your approach as well but  I have adopted another approach. Thank you. The output is different than what I am looking. Thank you so much for responding. I got the insight from your approach as to how I need to change my methods.

Comment: you are welcome and feel free to answer your own question as it might help someone in future.